# django set DateField from a DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-models

Quite simply this is my question:

```
class A(models.Model):
  x = DateTimeField(...)

class B(models.Model):
  x = DateField(...)
```

Given an instance of A and B, how do I simply set b.x to a.x? Simply setting b.x to a.x results in b.x being None.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime.datetime.date()` to get the `date` component like so:

```
a = A()
b = B()

# Stuff

b.x = a.x.date()
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects for more details.